# IntelliJ is formatting the entire file instead of the selected block for the Git clone project

Tags: java, github, intellij-idea, ide

IntelliJ is formatting the entire Java file when I press Ctrl+Alt+L. However, I've noticed that some lines are automatically getting reformatted after some time. I even tried using Ctrl+Shift+Alt+L, but the issue persists. This formatting problem is occurring only for the project that I cloned from GitHub. Interestingly, in a normal project that I created, the formatting works as expected without any automatic changes. Has anyone else faced or is currently facing this issue? Your help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.
Version : IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1

Comment: If you need to reformat code only manually ensure that reformat on save option is disabled in the IDE settings. Please see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/reformat-and-rearrange-code.html#reformat-on-save

Comment: @EgorKlepikov That one also didn't work, updated the intelij to 2023.1.4. After that am not facing that issue. Thank you.